# Getting SQL error while submitting form via ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a simple form with one input field and one submit button. When i click submit, i get error

This is the query in php. Query:

```
   //Using MySQLi
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `emailsubscribe` 
    (email,medium,country)VAlUE(?,?,?)"); // Use prepared statements. 
    $stmt-> bind_param("sss", $email, $medium, $country);
    $stmt-> execute();
```

This table has 3 columns email, medium and country.

```js
    $('#formoid').on('submit', function() {
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "subscribe.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
 success: function(data){
            $('.message').html(data).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<div class="message" style="color:black;"></div>
      <form action="subscribe.php" title="" method="post" id="formoid">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" minlength="7" size="40" placeholder="Enter your email here.." required><br><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="medium" value="subbox" />
        <input type="hidden" name="country" value="<?php echo $country; ?>" />
        <input type="submit">  
      </form>
```

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: P.s. the PHP code is a SQL injection disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: @ADyson This is the error. Notice: Undefined index: email . It looks like i have something wrong in ajax. isn't it?

Comment: @ADyson I really appreciate you pointing the SQL injection issue. Given my limited knowledge with SQL and other programming language i am lacking the expertise of fixing the issue. If you have something ready to be implemented regarding SQL injection issue, i would be happy to incorporate.

Comment: You can read about PDO and Prepared Statements. Those are some techniques to prevent such SQL injection issues

Comment: @user2852960 Actually I already wrote about solving the SQL injection problem in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62183376/include-more-data-to-be-sent-via-ajax-to-php-to-be-written-into-db), so please take a look there.

Comment: @Anu OP is using mysqli, not PDO.

Comment: @user2852960 As for your error, it's not quite clear why it happens, because you seem to have sent the email value correctly in your AJAX. When does it show the error exactly? Is it ever happening  _before_ you've run the AJAX? Perhaps your PHP doesn't check whether the request is a POST or not before proceeding - you need to wrap any code dealing with POST variables inside a `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {` block. That's the only thing I can think of. P.S.  the answer below is useful in terms of describing how to link the AJAX to your form fields.

Comment: @ADyson the SQL error was happening because the input fields required by subscribe.php were not passed when submit button was clicked. Does this ajax call require Jquery included?

Comment: Your whole code requires jQuery, not just the Ajax part. You would see an error in the browser's Console if jQuery wasn't included, and also the AJAX call would never have been sent to the server. Are you saying there was such an error?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's wrap up the HTML data.

```
<div class="message"></div>
<form action="subscribe.php" name="subscribeForm">
    <input type="email" name="emailsub" minlength="7" size="40" placeholder="Enter your email here.."><br><br>
    <select name="medium">
        <option value="">Select Medium</option>
        <option value="english">English</option>
        <option value="hindi">Hindi</option>
        <option value="japanese">Japanese</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <select name="country">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="action"> 
</form>
```

AJAX code below takes the form details and sends to `subscribe.php`. Note that `document.subscribeForm` below takes your form field variables and stores in the form. For this only `name` value in HTML part is enough. Hence, I have not added any `id` field in the HTML form fields.

```
$('#action').click(function() { 
    var form = document.subscribeForm;
    var dataString = $(form).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: $(form).attr("action"),
      data: dataString,
      beforeSend: function(){
        $('.message').hide();
        $("#action").val('Please wait...');
      },
      success: function(data){
        $('.message').html(data).fadeIn();
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Once the data is sent to `subscribe.php`, it's now time to process it.

```
// Storing data in variables
$email = (!empty($_POST['emailsub'])?$_POST['emailsub']:null;
$medium = (!empty($_POST['medium'])?$_POST['medium']:null;
$country = (!empty($_POST['country'])?$_POST['country']:null;

if($_POST){
    // Check if email submitted is empty or not. If yes, script will stop executing further.
    if($email == null){
        echo "Email is required";
        exit();
    }

    // Check if medium submitted is empty or not. If yes, script will stop executing further.
    if($medium == null){
        echo "Medium is required";
        exit();
    }

    // Check if country submitted is empty or not. If yes, script will stop executing further.
    if($country == null){
        echo "Country is required";
        exit();
    }

    // All checks cleared. Process the data.

    //Using MySQLi
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO emailsubscribe(email, medium, country)VAlUES(?,?,?)"); // Use prepared statements. 
    $stmt-> bind_param($email, $medium, $country);
    $stmt-> execute();

    // Using PDO (Better: A big bonus is that you can use a readable `:name` instead of confusing `?`)
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO emailsubscribe(email, medium, country)VAlUES(:email, :medium, :country)"); // Use prepared statements. 
    $stmt-> bindValue(':email', $email);
    $stmt-> bindValue(':medium', $medium);
    $stmt-> bindValue(':country', $country);
    $stmt-> execute();

    // Echo Message
    if($stmt){
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
}
```

This is the proper way how you should process your forms.

Comment: Please explain the code in a bit more detail, otherwise it's just a dump of data to be blindly copied, with no explanation of how or why it solves the problem. A good quality answer always includes a more detailed explanation

Comment: Also `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not needed here, because you're using parameterised queries. In fact it could even potentially be harmful by adding escaped characters into the data and thus changing it slightly. The parameterisation process will already take care of ensuring that special characters in the data are not interpreted as part of the SQL statement, so there's no use for mysqli_real_escape_string in this situation.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think `document.registerForm` will work though, I just noticed that, there's no form with that name in the HTML. But then again why did you change the OP's code from what it already was, where the form had an ID and the form's "submit" event was being handled by jQuery (instead of a button click)? Handling "submit" is generally the better approach, especially because then you can just write `$(this).serialize()` to directly serialise the current form, with no messing about.

Comment: P.S. `cache: true` is redundant - a) it's the default for this setting anyway, and b) it doesn't really apply to POST requests anyway, as mentioned in the $.ajax docs

Comment: yeah sorry, there were some minor mistakes... 1) It will be `document.subscribeForm` (2) Cache will be false... Didn't notice these earlier. (3) Even button click does the job well. If the user wants they can change to form submit.

Comment: I didn't mean change it to `cache:false`, I meant remove that line. Like I said, it has no effect either way on POST requests. Read the documentation for that parameter.

Comment: "Even button click does the job well"...it does but it requires more code. So like I said, why change from what the user originally had, which already worked? Don't overcomplicate it with too many changes for a beginner! Just my opinion, of course. Your answer is a lot better than it was now though.

Comment: I have made changes in the code. Noe using prepared stmt for SQL. i have updated the ajax, sql and html code in my original question. Now the problem is i am not able to show the success/failure response on the subscription box.

Comment: @user2852960 Are you able to insert data into the database?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I don't see any medium or country in your form as inputs. So I changed your HTML code

```js
$('#formoid').on('submit', function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "subscribe.php",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
      $(this).hide(); //sets css display:none to form
      var message = "Thank you!";
      $('.container-fluid').html(message);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<form action="subscribe.php" title="" method="post" id="formoid">
  <input type="email" id="emailsub" name="email" minlength="7" size="40" placeholder="Enter your email here.." required><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="" name="medium" size="40" placeholder="Enter here.." required>
  <input type="text" id="" name="country" size="40" placeholder="Enter here.." required>
  <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Then in your `subscribe.php` do the following. Take note, I just copied your exact SQL code. Use prepared statements or PDO to avoid SQL injection

```
$qry = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into `emailsubscribe` (email,medium,country) value ('".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['medium']."','".$_POST['country']."')");
```

Comment: yes although `FormData($('form')[0])` would be better as `FormData(this)` to 1) avoid confusion with any other forms potentially on the page, and b) avoid a pointless jQuery invocation. On the other hand, the code could be simplified - the lines `var FD = new FormData($('form')[0]);`, and `processData: false,
    contentType: false,` could all be removed, and `data: FD` replaced with `data: $(this).serialize()` to take advantage of jQuery's built-in ability to automatically collect form data - see https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Completely agree. But it seems the person is a beginner and thus I left all the details for him to see as it is.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your point in that respect - none of the stuff I've suggested changing was in the questioner's original code, so it won't do any harm for you to simplify the code you're providing in your answer. If you want something that's good for a beginner, then IMHO you should work hard not to clutter it up with irrelevant stuff. In that respect, `serialize()` is the best solution here because it's clear, simple and doesn't need lines of other code to make it work.

Comment: @ADyson I edited the code based on your suggestion. I think it looks cleaner now

Comment: Thank you @Anu. In the form, user will only enter email. The other two fields 1. medium is a string constant value like "subbox" 2. country is a two letter country code stored in a php variable $country. medium is used to capture from which place on the wep page user is subscribing as i have multiple points on the website from where user can subscribe. country is again to get the information from which country user has subscribed.

Comment: @user2852960 If those variables are not from the form, and instead hard coded, then you can directly type those in subscribe.php as hard coded variables. Don't need to pass through Ajax method. You can use session variable too if that is not the case.